# Scrolling Issue with a large number of items in a WinForms Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, scroll

I have noticed an issue with having a large number of items in a listbox winforms control.

In this simple test case example, I have 120,000 strings added to a listbox. I originally encountered this using a datatable bound to the listbox.DataSource, but it is reproducible this way as well:

```
listBox.BeginUpdate();
for(int x = 0; x < 120000; x++)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(x);
}
listBox.EndUpdate();
```

When I click and drag the scroll button from the top to the bottom, after I release the mouse, it moves the scroll button to the middle of the scroll bar.

This is a screenshot of where the button lands when I let it go from exactly at / near the bottom (I was precise and did not have the mouse outside of bounds of the scroll bar).

[image]

If I now click on the scroll bar button and move it 3/4/ the way down the length of the control, it will now pop back up to around 1/4th the way down the control length.

Has anyone else seen this and is there a known workaround? (I admittedly haven't looked into this next point) does this control have 'virtual modde' dynamic loading options like datagridview which might incidentally get rid of this strange hiccup?

Comment: the code that you are using for the Drag and Drop

Comment: [ListView.VirtualMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: also change this ` listBox.Items.Add(x);` to ` listBox.Items.Add(x.ToString());` and see if it makes any efficiency improvements.. other than that there you are implementing as well as using the for loop correctly

Comment: To address your multiple comments:
I am not using any drag and drop in the listbox.
Glad to see there is a virtualmode available. Do you by chance know if setting virtualmode fixes the scrolling issue?
The above code snippet was something I just hammered out as an example. It makes no difference to the scrolling issue if I add integers or strings. (My original issue occurred in an application with strings, not numbers)

Comment: I misread your Drag as drag and drop.. what happens when you change the code to add the x.ToString() have you also researched to see what the size limitations are for a Listbox in regards to the number of items it can contain..?

Comment: yes you can use Virtual I will post an example

Comment: You do know you get virtualization in WPF?  Are you stuck with WinForm?

Comment: @Blam - I could try making a WPF control library and use it in my winforms app. A workaround to consider. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to do this when you first load the form setup the property and its virtual size 
use a ListView instead of a ListBox

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.VirtualMode = true;
    listView1.VirtualListSize = 12000;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you are solving the wrong problem.  What is the use case for having such a large number of items in your listbox.   The general usage for a list box is for the user to select from the listed population.  Does your application really expect users to select specific items from such a large list of choices?

You would do your users (and your performance) a favor by providing a better way to narrow down the list for selection.

Comment: The answer is more or less, 'yes'. There is a jump to record and filter list using string UI function, but the implementation as it is now, the listbox does 'need' the capacity to scroll all records. I could re-implement it to show only records by a particular category, and not all categories (but that would be confusing as the filter function would have to ignore this), but it would still potentially have a large number of records (but maybe max 30,000 / category). A solution to consider, but I'd rather (and the users - who I just polled) would rather it work as is.

Comment: This pushed me in the direction of a potential workaround. I could use a small tabbed control with two tabs. Each with a list box. One works for searching and displays only when the user searches a search string, the other the user would be forced to pick a category and therefore the control would display fewer records. The problem still exists if they search in a way that returns all / most records, but this would avoid the problem most of the time. I'll probably just write my own control later to get around this completely

Comment: Without knowing what your app is doing and how the listbox is actually used by your users, its hard to say what the right answer is.  I will say though, in my 20+ years of building end-user apps, I have never found an acceptable use case for 100K+ items in a list being presented to the user, and no-one in my user communities would have accepted having to work with a list that long.   What is a user to do if the value they need to select is 100K items down the list?

Comment: You might want to post something on http://ux.stackexchange.com to get some feedback on how to manage a list of this size from the user perspective.

Comment: Thanks. I think ultimately you are right. While the contents of the listbox are not effectively useful without an effective search string, sometimes the number of records that match are the point. I need to separate these functions to overcome the scrolling bug on the off chance the user wants to scroll such a large number of records (which I admit - would be insane if you are really looking for something specific as opposed to randomly sampling, which in fact is often something users do while exploring the returned records)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the list box build in vertical scroll bar only can return the index from scroll position up to maximum 65535.  If the items added more than this value then will have the scrolling issue.  However, Vertical scroll bar control does not have this issue. It can scroll up to maximum of Int32.Max.  I just used the vertical scroll bar control instead of the default build in ListBox scroll bar

I add in another vertical scroll bar (vScrollBar1) and place it on right side of the list box to cover its original's list box vertical scroll bar.

Then Add below code for the vertical scroll bar that I create

```
private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) { listbox.TopIndex = 
e.NewValue; }

private void vScrollBar1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vScrollBar1.Maximum = listbox.Items.Count;
    }
```